# How can I read out the receiver and sender in the Reading Pane in Outlook with VB.net or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

How can I read out the receiver and sender in the Reading Pane in Outlook with VB.net or C#. It goes in a new window in which a new mail is created with

objOL = CreateObject ("Outlook.Application")

MsgBox ("objOL.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.To:" & objOL.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.To

It doesn't work in the reading pane (docked window).

Comment: show expected output or a screen shot of the result, do you want to show the message box when an email is received? Also the receiver will always be the Outlook account currently in use (unless you meant something else).

Comment: I want read the receiver and sender in the Reading Pane in Outlook, when the user answer a mail.There are two ways to answer a mail in Outlook. The first procedure is, when I click the Reply button in the ribbon bar, a new window opens to reply to the received mail. The second method is if I click the Reply button in the reading area of the mail, then I cannot see the sender and sender with the described method

objOL = CreateObject ("Outlook.Application")

MsgBox ("objOL.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.To:" & objOL.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.To

I don't how I can send you a screenshot?

Comment: ActiveInspector.CurrentItem will be populated when the user opens the email by double clicking it, you can attach a screenshot to your question if you edit it.